# Snowflake identifier column names

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has day01,day02 with prices. I want to be able to select the column name dynamically based on the date from the record in the table. I am trying this but not working.  I am getting a syntax error.

```
create or replace table tableA (
business_date date,
day01 integer,
day02 integer
)

insert into tableA values ('2023-01-01',1,2),('2023-01-02',3,4);

select (identifier(concat('day',right(business_date,2)))),business_date from tableA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT business_date, 
      CASE DAY(business_date) 
          WHEN 1 THEN day01
          WHEN 2 THEN day02
       END
FROM tableA;
```

or `DECODE`:

```
SELECT business_date, DECODE(DAY(business_date), 1, day01, 2, day02)
FROM tableA;
```

---

> I should be able to use identifier. It works if I do this `select (identifier('day01')),business_date from tableA;` But I cant get it working dynamically

```
 select identifier('day01'),business_date from tableA;
 -- here 'day01' is constant

 set var = 'day01';
 select identifier($var),business_date from tableA;
 -- variable, but the value after evaluation does not change
```

It is not possible to provide `IDENTIFIER` expression with column reference, because it will have to be evaluated for each row.

```
-- providing column name explicitly to be used for lookup
create or replace table tableA (
   business_date date,
   day01 integer,
   day02 integer,
   explicit_col_name TEXT
);

insert into tableA
values ('2023-01-01',1,2, 'day01'),
       ('2023-01-02',3,4, 'day02');

SELECT IDENTIFIER(explicit_col_name)
FROM tableA;
-- Syntax error: unexpected 'explicit_col_name'.
```

Comment: I can use cases but my actual query has 31 days and seems inefficient to write 31 cases.

Comment: @RyanBennett You need to define all 31 of them

Comment: I should be able to use identifier. It works if I do this select (identifier('day01')),business_date from tableA;  But I cant get it working dynamically

Comment: @RyanBennett I doubt you will be able to make  IDENTIFIER as expression  that varies per each row, but I would be delighted to be wrong.